# Using LocationManager.addGpsStatusListener with Android from JNI causes nothing to happen

Tags: java, android, gps

I have a strange issue I'm having trouble understanding. I can use LocationManager and its requestLocationUpdates method to receive location updates. I have a simple class that implements LocationListener:

```
  public class PrisLocationListener implements LocationListener
  {
     @Override
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
     { ... }

     @Override
     public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
     { ... }

     @Override
     public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
     { ... }

     @Override
     public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
     { ... }
  }
```

I use this class in my Activity by creating a separate thread for it:

```
    // create seperate thread for location callbacks
    mPrisLocationListener = new PrisLocationListener();
    mLocationHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("LocationHandlerThread");
    mLocationHandlerThread.start();
```

And then passing it to the LocationManager:

```
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,
                                            mPrisLocationListener,
                                            mLocationHandlerThread.getLooper());
```

The above works as expected and I can get the device's GPS location.

I also want GPS Status information (satellite count, TTFF, etc) so I create another class that implements GpsStatus.Listener:

```
  public class PrisGpsListener implements GpsStatus.Listener
  {
     @Override
     public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event)
     { ... }
  }
```

The trouble starts when I try to use the above class. At the same point in my Activity as for the LocationListener, I initialize an instance of the GpsListener and pass it to the LocationManager:

```
    mPrisGpsListener = new PrisGpsListener();
    if(!mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(mPrisGpsListener))   {
       Log.i("Activity: ","addGpsStatusListener failed"); // doesn't fail, addGpsStatusListener returns true
    }
    // LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates called after addGpsStatusListener
```

The problem is that if I add the 'addGpsStatusListener' call to my code, nothing happens with respect to location services. That is, not only do I not get any status updates from the GpsListener, but I don't get the normal location updates anymore either. Logcat doesn't show me anything at all when the relevant functions are called.

It's strange that requestLocationUpdates by itself works fine, but calling addGpsStatusListener to the mix makes everything fail. I have no idea what to try here so any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

EDIT:

As Rafael pointed out, all this works fine when called from Activity::onCreate()... however, (and this should have been one of the first things I mentioned), there's a separate function in my main Activity that calls the above LocationManager methods and instantiates the relevant objects. *I invoke the method from native code through JNI*

The method is called using JNI some time after the Activity is created.

Comment: Uh, sorry never worked with JNI myself. You could try if it makes any difference if you dont pass the WorkerThread's looper to LocationUpdates. Also make shure (ie with a Log) that this Method is really getting called. However you should also include your C code for the next one to read. Maybe your mistake was done in your native-code.

Comment: It turned out it kind of was a threading issue. I've explained what I understood in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

just tested this:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private PrisLocationListener mLocationListener;
private PrisGpsListener mGpsListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    PrisLocationListener locationListener = new PrisLocationListener();
    HandlerThread t = new HandlerThread("LocationHandlerThread");
    t.start();

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener, t.getLooper());

    mGpsListener = new PrisGpsListener();
    mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(mGpsListener);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
    mLocationManager.removeGpsStatusListener(mGpsListener);
}

public static class PrisLocationListener implements LocationListener{

    private static final String TAG = PrisLocationListener.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged: loc=" + arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: provider=" + provider);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: provider=" + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged: provider=" + provider + ", status=" + status + ", extras=" + extras);
    }

}

public static class PrisGpsListener implements GpsStatus.Listener{

    private static final String TAG = PrisGpsListener.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onGpsStatusChanged: event=" + event);
    }

}

}
```

My Log output

> 11-26 12:03:58.707: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=1
>   11-26 12:04:00.199: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4
>   11-26 12:04:01.199: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4
>   11-26 12:04:02.199: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4
>   11-26 12:04:03.207: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4
>   11-26 12:04:04.207: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4
>   11-26 12:04:05.199: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4
>   11-26 12:04:06.199: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4
>   11-26 12:04:07.191: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4
>   11-26 12:04:08.207: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4
>   11-26 12:04:09.215: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4
>   11-26 12:04:10.207: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4
>   11-26 12:04:11.207: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4
>   11-26 12:04:12.207: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4
>   11-26 12:04:13.215: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4
>   11-26 12:04:14.223: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4
>   11-26 12:04:15.223: D/PrisGpsListener(24412): onGpsStatusChanged: event=4

So `GpsStatus.Listener` is actually working. I guess you will recieve Location fixes if you move your phone.

Comment: I realized that it works for me too with the methods called in onCreate(). Please see my updated question ... and sorry for not mentioning the additional details (I didn't think they were relevant until I tried your code out).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I needed to call LocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(...) from the main thread. Enclosing the call with a Runnable did the trick:

```
 public void someFunctionCalledWithJNI()
 {
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()   {
       public void run()   {
          if(!mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(mPrisGpsListener))   {
             Log.i("Activity: ","addGpsStatusListener failed");
          }
       }
    });
 }
```

The same thing applies to LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates, but that throws an exception that explicitly tells you: "Can't create Handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()", so I had created a separate HandlerThread for it.

You can also just keep both on the main thread:

```
 public void someFunctionCalledWithJNI()
 {
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()   {
       public void run()   {
          if(!mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(mPrisGpsListener))   {
             Log.i("Activity: ","addGpsStatusListener failed");
          }
          mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,mPrisLocationListener); 
       }
    });
 }
```

Comment: nice, maybe it helps a fellow reader with the same issue. Always best to find the issue yourself.